# Symfony - ChoiceType filled with array

Tags: php, symfony

(Sorry for my english, I'm french ^^)

I have been trying for several days to have a select for a form with a somewhat special ChoiceType.
I want the select to contain for example all the names of the zoos of France (which are registered in my BDD in an entity)but I want to be able to add choices manually like "Laboratory", "Others", for example to have the list of zoos + Laboratory + Others in one select... . (So ​​that's why I don't take the entityType, because I don't want to create a table just for them. I would like it to be detached choices).

So I started by doing this, in my formtype.

```
public function getZooName()
{

    $allZoos = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Zoo::class)->findAll();

    $zoosName = [];
    foreach ($allZoos as $zoo) {
        $zooName = $zoo->getName();
        $zoosName[$zooName] = $zoo->getName(); //If I don't do this, I have 0, 1, 2 ... in the select instead of the name
    }
        return $zoosName;
}
```

And then, in the buildForm I have:

```
->add('origin', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'choices' => [
                 $this->getZooName(),
                'Labo'=>'LABO',
                'Autre'=>'AUTRE'    
            ], 
        ])
```

[This is what I have with all of this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYX7x.png)

I don't understand where the "0" comes from ...
As I am still a beginner, I surely did something wrong !
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the `choices` parameter must be an array. You are passing in an array, with three values: `Labo`, `Autre` and *the array returned by `getZooName()`*.

So effectively, you have this:

```php
$choices = [
    [
        'Paris Zoo' => 'Paris Zoo',
        'Lion Zoo' => 'Lion Zoo'
    ],
    'Labo' => 'LABO',
    'Autre' => 'AUTRE'
];
```

What you should do is add `Labo` and `Autre` to the result of `getZooName()`

```php
$choices = $this->getZooName();
$choices['Labo'] = 'LABO';
$choices['Autre'] = 'AUTRE';

->add('origin', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'choices' => $choices, 
        ])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried but I still have the "0". 

I added $zoosName ['Laboratory'] = "Laboratory"; for example, right after my getZooName foreach.

Comment: Reading it again, I think the example code I posted might have been unclear, so I updated it. Can you verify that this is what you are doing, @LucieBrochet ?

Comment: Yes thank you it works ! I still have [ ] for the choices ! 
Thank you !